# SAPUI5 Two oData Datasources within manifest / descriptor

Tags: odata, manifest, sapui5

i'm using SAPUI5 Version gt 1.30 and I try to define the automatic model instantiation of two external services within the manifest.

My first question is, are more than one odata services allowed? Sorry, but i'cant find it out by the documentation.

The default datasource ("") works. But the second datasource ("HLA") not. 
If more than once are allowed, please could somebody look for the right definition.

```
"sap.app":
    "dataSources": {
        "mainService": {
            "uri": "path.xsodata/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
            }
        }
        "secondService": {
            "uri": "/path.......xsodata/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "annotations": [],
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "localUri": ""
            }
        }
    },


"sap.ui5":
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "....i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "": {
            "dataSource": "mainService",
            "settings": {
                "metadataUrlParams": {
                    "sap-documentation": "heading"
                }
            }
        },
        "HLA": {
            "dataSource": "secondService",
            "settings": {
                "metadataUrlParams": {
                    "sap-documentation": "heading"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It surely is possible.. have you tried "cleaning" your manifest file? Some of these properties look unnecessary and may be the cause for your problem.

Comment: okay, thanks! Then I'll give it a try again.

Comment: You might want to try replacing your main datasource with your second datasource. Or switch them (make HLA your main service). If HLA still doesn't work after the replacement/switch, it's more likely that there is a mistake in the setup of the second service (HLA).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have solved your problem, but I encountered the same problem today too. And I realise you need to use different notations when binding those two data sources to a control. I'm using XML view btw.

For the default "" model:

```
<Table id="table" inset="true" items="{/}" >
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="ID"/>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Name"/>
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{id}"/>
                <Text text="{name}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

For the second model named "Users":

```
<Table id="userTable" inset="true" items="{Users>/}">
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="ID"/>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Last Name"/>
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{Users>empNumber}"/>
                <Text text="{Users>lastName}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

It works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can have more than one data source, but it is recommended by the fiori guidelines to only use one.

Do you want your address to look like this path.......xsodata/ ?

Also I think you should remove the localUri from the second data source.
Because if there is no metadata document this might throw an arror.

```
"secondService": {
    "uri": "/proxy/service.xsodata",
    "type": "oData",
    "settings": {
        "odataVersion": "2.0"
    }
}
```

What is the output of the debugger? Do you get an error?
Also your oData model should have a type.

```
"HLA": {
    "dataSource": "secondService",
    "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel"
}
```

Comment: Hi Arwed, thanks for you reply. "Of course you can have more than one data source, but it is recommended by the fiori guidelines to only use one." Sorry, but couldn't find this point in the fiori guidelines. Where have you seen it?